# Combining two regexes

Tags: json, regex

I'm trying to combine two regexes. One will ensure that input contains 14 digits: `^\\d{14}$` and I need another regex to check if all the input is not of the same digit.
Please suggest how I proceed with this. I want my regex to check for that the input is 14 digits and those digits are not all same numbers [0-9].

Is there a way I add the test for finding not all digits are the same with my regex that checks for if the input is exactly 14 digits? I would need one regex expression which combines them both. Thank you!

Comment: `I would need one regex expression` - why? If you have two working ones why not just use them in sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead with a back reference to the first digit:

[`(?!(\d)\1{13})\d{14}$`](https://regex101.com/r/DpRAdR/1)

NB: This is pure regex syntax. I did not escape backslashes for use in a programming language.

Comment: This exactly what I needed. Thank you so much and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

There is no regex operation for "match here for all-of-these except a back-reference". You have a two-step test here, not a single one.